# How to prevent page manual swiping in SwipeView

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

How to prevent page manual swiping in `SwipeView`? I would like to swipe current index just by interaction with buttons. How can I achieve that? Here is my QML code:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.0

ApplicationWindow {

    property int globalForJs: 10;

    id: mainWindow
    visible: true
    width: 1024
    height: 768
    color: '#ffffff'
    signal qmlSignal(string msg)

    TopPanel {
        id: topPanel1
    }

    SwipeView {
        id: view
        currentIndex: 0
        anchors.fill: parent

        Rectangle {
            id: firstPage
            color: "red"
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: secondPage
            color: "blue"
        }
    }


    BottomPanel {
        id: bottomPanel1
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An `interactive` property [was added recently](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-54268), and will be available in the Qt 5.8 alpha.

If you can't use 5.8, and you know that the type of the [`contentItem`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-control.html#contentItem-prop) is a [`Flickable`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-flickable.html) (which it currently is for all built-in styles), you can set its `interactive` property to `false`:

```
Component.onCompleted: contentItem.interactive = false
```